# Closing a Content dialog after some event on a web view

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a content dialog in my UWP application with just a web view in it. this web view basically shows a web page that asks for some user response.Once the user submits their response , I want to close this dialog.
 content.xaml:

```
 <localControls:CustomContentDialog
        x:Class="Microsoft.ABC.Desktop.Views.RatingDialog">
         <WebView name="Webview1" height="400" width="650"/>
    </localControls:CustomContentDialog>
```

Any idea how can I close this content dialog once I get some reponse from the loaded webpage?

Comment: 1. You can invoke custom script of your webpage and can get the result back in your App. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#interacting-with-webview-content) MSDN article. 2. Add Close button in your content dialog so that user can close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how can I close this content dialog once I get some reponse from the loaded webpage?

You could use `window.external.notify` from the HTML to notify the application then monitor the message with [`ScriptNotify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify)event handler. you could following code. for more please refer [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) official document.

**content.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit() {
            window.external.notify('true');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CustomContentDialog.cs**

```
public sealed partial class CustomContentDialog : ContentDialog
{
    public CustomContentDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ContentDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ContentWebView.ScriptNotify += ContentWebView_ScriptNotify;
    }

    private void ContentWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString().Equals("true"))
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }

}
```